# Can this be considered a dialogue tag?

Tags: punctuation, commas, writing, dialogue

Lately, I've been pondering about this question.

First of all, we already know that dialogue tags consist of a noun or a pronoun followed by a verb like "said," and "ask."

> "Like this one," I said.

Also, when using an action tag, the dialogue must have a full stop.

> "Like this?" I looked at the text above.

Would "is my only answer" be considered a dialogue tag with that structure? I can't really consider it one since it doesn't have the same structure.

> "I don't know," is my only answer.